# Which NPCs detect when Jensen is using Social Enhancer pheromones?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I keep hearing that several NPCs detect when Jensen is using Social Enhancer pheromones to sway them, but I can't find a list with them anywhere. Has anyone tried to use pheromones on a NPC and was detected?

Answer (score 8):

The only one I know of that "detects" it is Malik, when you're convincing her to give out her reason for visiting the Alice Garden Pods.

She doesn't so much 'detect' it so much as it's:

> (After selecting: "use Pheremones")
>
> "Jensen, you better not be trying
> to use that damn CASIE mod on me"
>
> "I... wouldn't... dream of it."

Comment: To add to this, there are a few people that *seem* to detect you when you screw up and pick the wrong choice.

Answer (score 6):

Also in the side quest "Talion AD" on the second visit to Heng Sha, Zelazny also notices when you use pheremones.